# describe and select on table in derby doesn't use same column order as create

Tags: java, derby

I've come across and interesting behaviour in derbyDB.

I create a table with the following SQL (from java code)...

```
Create Table S1.SortieDessai (OBS VARCHAR(9), DateDUSortie TIMESTAMP, ContreIndic BOOLEAN,
Fin BOOLEAN, PdeVu VARCHAR(255), Refus LONG VARCHAR , InvDecisn LONG VARCHAR ,
Admin LONG VARCHAR , Motif_de_la_sortie VARCHAR(255), NomValidee VARCHAR(255),
DateValidee TIMESTAMP )
```

However when I call a describe from ij I get the following...

```
ij> describe sortiedessai;
COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME|DEC&|NUM&|COLUM&|COLUMN_DEF|CHAR_OCTE&|IS_NULL&
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OBS                 |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|9     |NULL      |18        |YES
CONTREINDIC         |BOOLEAN  |NULL|NULL|1     |NULL      |NULL      |YES
FIN                 |BOOLEAN  |NULL|NULL|1     |NULL      |NULL      |YES
PDEVU               |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|255   |NULL      |510       |YES
REFUS               |LONG VAR&|NULL|NULL|32700 |NULL      |NULL      |YES
INVDECISN           |LONG VAR&|NULL|NULL|32700 |NULL      |NULL      |YES
ADMIN               |LONG VAR&|NULL|NULL|32700 |NULL      |NULL      |YES
MOTIF_DE_LA_SORTIE  |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|255   |NULL      |510       |YES
NOMVALIDEE          |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|255   |NULL      |510       |YES
DATEDUSORTIE        |DATE     |0   |10  |10    |NULL      |NULL      |YES
DATEVALIDEE         |DATE     |0   |10  |10    |NULL      |NULL      |YES
```

When I do a select * the columns are reported in the same order as the above describe.

This had caused me a problem when 'copying' tables from one DBMS to another. The other DBMS (Ms Access) reports the column names in the order of the create statement, so when i do the insert I can't rely on the order in Derby being 'correct' as reported from Access, this means I have to play around a bit more to get a good order and then get the values to insert in that order, not a great hardship, but agravating.

Also when I create my table I put the information that I want to see first at the begining of my create statement, assuming that any *select ** commands will spit out the results in the same order.

This leads me to a couple of questions.

Can I tell derby to report in a specific order (ie creation order) for tables in a setting somewhere?
Is derby doing some strange behaviour that is a bug, or is it something about the statement object? (I've tried both statement.execute(sqlString) and statement.executeUpdate(sqlString) and both seem to have the same effect - I assume for the instant it is a java thing, as if I create the table within ij everything works in the correct order.

How does derby determine how to report the order of columns in any given table, it looks like it is random, but whatever order I use the column in the create statement the describe is always the same!

Note: I have become aware that Access does have a habit of spitting some info out in what seems like a completely random order (ie list of table names from the databaseMetaData never output in the same order, but resultSetMetadata seems to be correctly ordered).

Any thoughts will be greatefully accepted

Partial solution and more info.
See me comments for using an array to store the order of column names and extacting the data in the same order. its not very 'nice' but it solved the problem.
I also should add that I test my data (which incidently comes from an ms Access source) and confirm the correct type in some circumstances (Namely the single datetime in Access doesn map easily to timestamp/date/time).
So I modify the data type of the column. Obviously this modification alters the structure by adding and removing a column, this also helps to mess up the 'structured' order of the initial insert.
Until I get a chance to write a propper test case I can't guarantee that this isn't the root cause of my problem!

Comment: 10.9 the most recent stable. As I have stated to Barry below, I have solved my issue by catching the column names in an array, then using the order in the array to get the actual data in the good order.

Comment: Maybe so, but have you reported the behavior as a Derby bug report or checked the mailing list? It doesn't seem correct to me, and a report might help them fix it.

Comment: @Bill I haven't found anything on the mailing list. I'm not about to report a bug until I have confirmed the 'strange behaviour', also I need to get the info that Bryan has requested to check this out. Also I don't have time to write a test scenario at this moment in time. Once I have one, I will be able to file a bug report (if it really is a bug). Untill then I'm not willing to file it as a bug. Also see my last edit 'partial solution' The more I study it the more I wonder if actually I was modifying the table in one of the many logic cases that I have going on. So good old user error!

Comment: It's probably worth re-titling or re-wording this question/document to make it more apparent that it's the ALTER TABLE statement which is changing the column ordering. By the way, are you actually adding a new column and dropping the old column? Or are you doing ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN? I know that some data type modifications can be performed without needing to drop and re-add the column; others can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite odd that the order depends on whether you create the table via ij, or whether you create the table from your Java program. If you can isolate this to a simple test case, you should consider reporting it to the Derby developers as a bug, as I don't think it should be this way.

To dig into the details more deeply, try looking at the way the colums are laid out in the `SYSCOLUMNS` system table, and in particular at the values for the `COLUMNNUMBER` column in that table.

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsistabs22441.html

Are you getting the same results in the `SYSCOLUMNS` table when you create your table in ij versus from your Java application?

Comment: I'll have to check, when I get the chance. for now i capture the list and store the column names in a String[array]. Then use this to order the start of the insert, and correctly order the values from the result set. Which solves the problem and is an acceptable (and not overly difficult workaround - in fact it makes the code easier to read, if it does add a few extra lines)

Comment: @barry I decide to use another simple test class. And on this one the insert (sent from java) and select and describe (from ij) concur on the details? I can only imagine my auto generation of the SQL in my other test scenario doesn't work somehow. I log the SQL statement that I send (which is what I pasted above). I'm no longer sure if this is a java (ResultSetMetaData from a MS Access result set), ij, or me being a sloppy programmer.... I'l keep an eye out for the problem again later on, and check in my original test scenario.

Comment: I finally got around to working out what was happening. It is exactly as I suggested in my edit when I change the data type of the field, and need to add the new field and remove the old. I don't know if it is possible to then give the new field the same reference values in the **SYSCOLUMNS** as the original. Personally my solution works, albeit a bit of a hack (in my view). I don't know if you would call this a bug or not?

Comment: Ah, so the ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN statement is changing the column's ordering as a side effect? I guess I'm not surprised to hear that. At the least, the Derby documentation could note that side effect.

Comment: Its not so much the ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN as the way in which I have to perform it to 'work around' the problem causes when trying to import the data into derby from an old MS Access db. It would be good if there was a was to give a 'new column' in a table the same reference value as the original (now deleted) reference. Though I'm not sure that I want to play around too much with system columns, however as you say a note in the docs would probably not go amiss.

Comment: @DaveM I rejected your edit suggestion. If you need to edit an answer with the 'real' solution, then you're better off writing a new answer. The "complete view of the problem/solution" shouldn't be in the hands of the reader to discern. You may give credit to an answer by upvoting it, but the accepted answer to your question should either be an existing answer (which you don't have to modify), or a new one.